# Asp.net image control

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I have a web page that will display an image (ie a logo).
I am using the following code but the image is not being displayed in the image control.

Image1.ImageUrl = "C:\logo.jpg".

is there any way to display that image?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder within your website called 'images' and read the image from there; because the website is set up with a virtual directory, it doesn't have the concept of reading directly from a referenced path on your machine for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I created such a directory.But still it is not working.Should i change something in properties?